# why quasar dev not working, when execute quasar dev?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a problem whit quasar when I run:  `quasar dev`, and don't want run

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed

1. Checked that the port 8080 is free.
2. Check if there is a new version of vue-cli or quasar-cli.
3. Try `quasar clean` and `quasar dev` again.

Answer (score 3):

just add
`npx quasar build` 
or
`npx quasar dev`  etc